# QGIS v2. Convert longitude/latitude to UTM projection-Zone 51J - Southern hemisphere

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

Could somebody please let me know in QGIS version 2.0.1
How do I convert Longitude/latitude default setting to UTM projection.
I am bringing in waypoints from a GPS device which is set to the above specifications
ie UTM projection/Zone 51J/Southern Hemisphere
BUT when I bring the waypoints into QGIS version 2.0.1 it displays  files as longitude/latitude. Can I change settings somewhere???

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  With such a brief statement in the area reserved for your Question, I suspect you will have difficulty attracting responses other than links to possible duplicates.  However, if you use the edit button beneath your Question to revise it with more details about what you have done and tried to do then it is likely to fare better.

Comment: Data from GPS devices imported from GPX files or directly from the device is always in WGS84 according to the GPX specifications. This is independent from the device settings to **display** coordinates.

Comment: Lisa if the linked question is not an answer, please feel free to add more detail which explains how this Q is different and flag for re-opening.

Answer (score 2):

Go to project properties and select Project Coordinate System !!

[image]